# Best method to extract information from unstructured text

Tags: python, r, solr, nlp, text-mining

My aim is to extract information from old scanned reports and store in the structured database. I have already extracted text from these reports using Solr.

All of these are scientific reports and have a different structure in terms of the content of the report, but all of these has similar information. I wanted to a create a structured database using these reports such as name of the company involved in the report, name of the software involved in the report, name of the location, date of the experiment etc. For each of these fields, I have some keywords which shall be used for extraction, For example for the Location information: Location, Place of experiment, Place, Facility etc. What will be the best way to proceed in the direction?

Also, in some of these files, there are no sentences to process. Information is given in Form like structure, for example:

Location: Canada

Date of the experiment: 1985-05-01.

Which techniques will be best to extract the information? also which software, libraries should I use?

Comment: Try the tidytext package to put your text into a tibble (data frame) that has one row for each word in each report.  Then add variables for each of the fields you want to extract, using the stringr package.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know